# Json in sharepoint column help

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am not a developer and need some help please.  I currently have 2 columns in SharePoint that display buttons based on conditions. Both sets of JSON work just fine.

Basically I want to have only 1 column and based on some condition, apply the correct JSON to it.  I think ideally I am after and if,then,else of the merged JSON's.

So, if condition is true use JSON 1, if not use JSON 2.

Can this be done?  Here are my 2 JSON codes:

JSON 1:

```
{
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Request this Software",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"08768563-511b-4f29-afd9-88d3e72a26d6\", \"headerText\":\"Confirm you want to request this software and that you have budget holder approval already\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Click Here To Confirm Request\"}"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "blue",
    "color": "white",
    "visibility": "=if(([$VisibleButton] == true) && ([$Status] != 'Rejected') ,'visible','hidden')"
  }
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Request this Software",
      "style": {
        "background-color": "purple",
        "color": "white",
        "visibility": "=if(([$VisibleButton] == false) && ([$Status] != 'Rejected') ,'visible','hidden')"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add both the JSON elements as children of single `div` element and then handle their visibility based on the conditions you can want to apply

Try using something like below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "button",
            "txtContent": "Request this Software",
            "customRowAction": {
                "action": "executeFlow",
                "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"08768563-511b-4f29-afd9-88d3e72a26d6\", \"headerText\":\"Confirm you want to request this software and that you have budget holder approval already\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Click Here To Confirm Request\"}"
            },
            "style": {
                "background-color": "blue",
                "color": "white",
                "visibility": "=if(([$VisibleButton] == true) && ([$Status] != 'Rejected') ,'visible','hidden')"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "href": "@currentField",
                "target": "_blank"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "txtContent": "Request this Software",
                    "style": {
                        "background-color": "purple",
                        "color": "white",
                        "visibility": "=if(([$VisibleButton] == false) && ([$Status] != 'Rejected') ,'visible','hidden')"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Amazing.  Works brilliantly with one exception.  The column is now effecrtively double width, allowing space for one button or the other.  Is there a way they can occupy the same screen space so the column in 1 button wide?

Comment: instead of using `visibility` style property use `display` property. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone) for more clarification and differences.