# Column Formatting with Approval Status

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I got this problem:

I have a button which should only be visible when the Approval Status is not "Genehmigt".

This is the JSON I got right now:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json&#8221",
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "color": "#0078d7"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "style": {
        "background-color": "green",
        "color": "white",
        "visibility": "if ([$Approval Status] == 'Genehmigt';false;true)"
      },
      "txtContent": "Freigabe anfordern",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"304887e9-d4dc-431c-8383-9fda6b226991\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here nothing appears. Also tried it with `[$ModerationStatus]` also didn't work.

Hope you guys can help me with this!

Comment: Is this SharePoint default approval status column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint JSON formatting, you have to use the [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of list column. You can get the internal name of any of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

If you are using SharePoint default Approval Status column, you need to use `_ModerationStatus` in your formula.

like:

```
"visibility": "=if([$_ModerationStatus] == 'Genehmigt', 'visible', 'hidden')"
```

OR

```
"display": "=if([$_ModerationStatus] == 'Genehmigt', 'block', 'none')"
```

If you are using the custom column you created, find out the internal name of your column using above link & use it instead.

**Related posts**:

1. [Display different flow buttons in sharepoint list with time condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285148/display-different-flow-buttons-in-sharepoint-list-with-time-condition/285151#285151)
2. [Json in sharepoint column help](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278024/json-in-sharepoint-column-help/278030#278030)

---

**Update**:

Microsoft is adding official support for Approval Status column in JSON formatting.

Due to this update, the `@currentField` and `[$_ModerationStatus]` will resolve to internal code ([enum value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype)) and `@currentField.displayValue` and `[$_ModerationStatus.displayValue]` will resolve to the localized string.

The Microsoft official docs will be updated with more info in the coming weeks. You can check the details for now at: [SharePoint Online Column Formatting for Approval Status: uses language specific text?](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6731#issuecomment-951811850)

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesnt work.
Its the default sharepoint column

Comment: Can you please check the internal name of your column? (add screenshot if possible)

Comment: i cant find the column right here. is ther another way to get the internal name? https://i.stack.imgur.com/swG0m.png

Comment: I tested it my end, you need to use `[$_ModerationStatus]`, check updated answer. Also make sure you have added approval status field in list view.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work anymore. You need to do [$_ModerationStatus.displayValue] or @currentField.displayValue. See [GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6731)