# Json formatting - How to use the Moderation Status field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I have activated content approval on my list and I would like to format my form using the configure layout option to have a header that changes color based on the Approval Status Column.

But the no matter what I change my header keeps showing red.
Is the `$_ModerationStatus` the right one to use?

See JSON below:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "justify-content": "space-between",
        "border-radius": "10px",
        "padding": "18px",
        "font-size": "24px"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if([$_ModerationStatus] == 'Approved', 'ms-bgColor-greenLight', if([$_ModerationStatus]  == 'Draft', 'ms-bgColor-blueLight', if([$_ModerationStatus]  == 'Pending', 'ms-bgColor-warning', if([$_ModerationStatus] == 'Rejected', 'ms-bgColor-red', 'ms-bgColor-orangeLight')))) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary'"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "textDocument",
                "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                "title": "Details"
            },
            "style": {
                "flex": "none",
                "padding": "0px",
                "padding-left": "0px",
                "height": "36px"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$Title]"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "=if([$_ModerationStatus]  == 'Approved', 'CompletedSolid', if([$_ModerationStatus]  == 'Draft', 'PinnedSolid', if([$_ModerationStatus]  == 'Pending', 'TestBeakerSolid', if([$_ModerationStatus]  == 'Rejected', 'WarningSolid', 'Blocked2Solid'))))",
                "title": "[$Status]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try using `[$_ModerationStatus.displayValue]` instead of `[$_ModerationStatus]`.

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, does below answer help you in any way?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.Will update soon

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, does below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft added official support for Approval Status column in JSON formatting sometime back.

Due to this update, the `@currentField` and `[$_ModerationStatus]` will resolve to internal code ([enum value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype)) and `@currentField.displayValue` and `[$_ModerationStatus.displayValue]` will resolve to the localized string.

So, try using `[$_ModerationStatus.displayValue]` instead of `[$_ModerationStatus]` in your JSON or use enum values to compare instead of text value.

- 0 : Approved
- 1 : Denied
- 2 : Pending
- 3 : Draft
- 4 : Scheduled

**Similar thread**: [Column Formatting with Approval Status](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290641/column-formatting-with-approval-status)

---

**Update**:

As per the current design of SharePoint JSON formatting, you can refer only those columns which are shown on list forms in your JSON.

Seems like Approval Status column is not visible in list forms hence you are unable to use its value in JSON formatting.

**Similar thread**: [Can ID column be displayed when configuring a list form header using JSON?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292429/can-id-column-be-displayed-when-configuring-a-list-form-header-using-json)

**Example**:

For simple SharePoint list with only Title and Approval Status column, I can only see the Title column on list form and only below column values are available in page context while applying JSON in header layout:

[image]

**Related Read**: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)